# Preencher tabelas com várias chaves estrangeiras

Tags: mysql, modelo-relacional, chave-estrangeira

Eu tenho uma base de dados com as seguintes tabelas:

- **Aeroporto** ( iata **PK**, aeroporto, cidade, estado, pais, lat, long)
- **Causa_Cancelamento** ( codigoCancelamento **PK**, descricao)
- **Fabricante** (IDfabricante **PK**, nome_fabricante)
- **Modelo** (IDmodelo **PK**, nome_modelo, nome_fabricante **FK**)
- **CompanhiaAerea**(codigoCompanhia **PK**, descricao)
- **TipoAviao** (IDtipoAviao **PK**, tipo_aviao)
- **Tipo_Motor** (IDtipo_motor **PK**, tipo_motor)
- **TipoLicenca** (IDTipo_licenca **PK**, tipo_licenca)
- **Aviao** (codAviao **PK**, IDModelo **FK**, IDTipo_licenca **FK**, CodigoCompanhia **FK**, IDtipoAviao **FK**, IDTipo_Motor **FK**, data_registo, estado, ano)
- **Voo** (IDvoo **PK**, codigoCancelamento **FK**, CodAviao**FK**, iata_origem **FK**, iata_destino **FK**, Datavoo, Hora_partida_real, Hora_partida_prevista, Hora_chegada_real, Hora_chegada_prevista, FlightNum, AtualElapsedTime, TempoVoo, distancia, cancelado)

> Nota: PK - Primary Key; FK - Foreign Key

A fonte dos dados são ficheiros *csv*. O *csv* principal tem milhões de registros e todas as informações relativas aos voos. Os restantes são ficheiros *csv* suplementares com informações acerca do avião, companhia aérea e aeroporto.

A minha dúvida é: qual é a forma mais simples/eficaz de carregar correctamente os dados das chaves estrangeiras das tabelas Avião e voo?

Comment: Tudo, portanto, está em CSV e você precisa dar uma carga inicial no seu banco de dados? Ou essa carga terá que ser feita periodicamente?

Comment: Algumas tabelas consigo carregar directamente como é o caso de Aeroporto, tipo de motor e etc. Já em relação às tabelas Avião e voo isso não é possível porque são necessárias algumas correspondências de dados para que tudo esteja de forma correta, talvez com recurso a INNER JOIN's. Por exemplo num dos ficheiros csv cada registo corresponde  um voo e possui os campos "Código de avião", "companhia aérea", "numero de voo" e etc. O csv que tem os dados dos aviões não possui a companhia aérea a que pertence cada avião, daí ter que fazer uma correspondência entre o código avião nas duas tabelas

Answer (score 0):

No MySQL, você pode usar um recurso dele chamado de LOAD DATA INFILE.

> The  LOAD DATA INFILE statement allows you to read data from a text
>   file and import the file’s data into a database table very fast.

Com ele, você pode carregar diretamente um CSV do seu sistema de arquivos e passar para uma tabela do banco de dados MySQL.

Se você tem uma tabela Aviao (abstrai alguns campos pois não tenho os detalhes da sua tabela):

```
CREATE TABLE Aviao (
  codAviao INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data_registro DATE NOT NULL,
  nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (codAviao )
);
```

E um CSV chamado avioes.csv, com este conteúdo:

```
codAviao, data_registro, nome
1, 20150809, "Aviao 1"
2, 20140809, "Aviao 2"
```

Você pode importar desta maneira (com o arquivo avioes.csv localizado em c:/tmp/):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/avioes.csv' 
INTO TABLE discounts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Mais detalhes você pode encontrar aqui: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/

Para garantir a integridade das informações ao final do processo, uma vez que você (provavelmente) precisará inserir informações de tabelas relacionadas ainda não importadas em uma das importações, basta no início da importação desabilitar a verificação de chave estrangeira:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

e depois habilitar novamente, ao final da importação:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Não se trata simplesmente de carregar dados, isso consigo fazer dessa mesma maneira que falou. A minha dúvida é como carregar os dados das chaves estrangeiras, esses não são possíveis carregar dessa forma pois não estão todos no mesmo csv nem é possível juntá-los. Terão que ser feitas algumas correspondências de dados de forma a que tudo bata certo

Comment: @PedroCunha, veja a resposta atualizada :)